# How can I write just one query whose only difference is in the where clause, to capture logic of a boolean test?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

On an Oracle 11g  engine using PL/SQL
I have logic that runs like this

```
if (flag = Y) then 
   select id, flavor, color
   from menu
   where flavor in (1,2,3,4,5);
else 
   select 
   id, flavor, color
from 
   menu
   where flavor in (2,4,6);
end if;
```

I'm thinking using decode or case logic in the **where** clause? I'd like to have just one query that can handle both 'flag' values.

Comment: I'm assuming your code actually does something with the result from each SELECT? Because PL/SQL doesn't automatically return records like T-SQL does...

Comment: Not much other than report..I capture the result set and print it to a report. Basically, if flag = Y, run report A if flag<>Y run very similar report B..I'm using a cursor to loop through the result set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you just change it to use an OR?  (assumed that flag it N if not Y, but may be NULL which will be treated as N)

```
  select 
   id, flavor, color
from 
   menu
   where 
        (flag = 'Y' and flavor in (1,2,3,4,5))
        or(nvl(flag,'N') = 'N' and flavor in (2,4,6)) ;
```

if you want to check for flag <> Y (in a similar fashion as @Crappy Coding Guy posted, but it can be NULL, changing

> nvl(flag,'N') = 'N'

to

> nvl(:flag,'N') <> 'Y'

will suffice

Answer (score 1):

The logical and comparison operators in Oracle might be a little different, but something like this should do the trick.

```
select id, flavor, color
from menu
where (flag = Y and flavor in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
      or (flag != Y and flavor in (2, 4, 6)
```

Comment: only caveat here, is if FLAG is null this will return no results

Comment: Yeah, this would require tweaking the _or_ clause if _NULL_ is a possibility.